# i3wm doesn't move Inkscape to workspace assigned

Tags: configuration, window-manager, i3, tiling-wm

suddenly, i3 stopped moving Inkscape to the workspace I assigned to it. I really cannot understand why it is doing this, because it was just working fine like two days ago.

I'll post the code I wrote in i3/config to move Inkscape to the ninth workspace and to move me as well to that workspace:

```
for_window [class="Inkscape"] move to workspace $ws9 workspace number $ws9
```

Moreover, this is the output of xprop used on the Inkscape window:

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "org.inkscape.Inkscape", "Inkscape"
```

If you need anything else, let me know.

(I checked that the name of the workspace is actually $ws9)

One thing I noticed is that it doesn't move only when I open it in workspaces where I have other windows; if it is in an empty workspace, it will be moved to the ninth one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, and changing a few settings on Inkscape solved it for me.

Open Inkscape, go to Edit > Preferences. On the Preferences window, go to Interface > Windows. Then set the "Default window size" to **Default**, and "Saving window geometry (size and position)" to **Don't save window geometry**.

Comment: This makes sense. I just put OP's `for_window` line into my `.config/i3/config` and couldn't reproduce. So the problem wasn't related to the `i3wm` version or the command itself.  It was interference from something else.  Fortunately, you found it.